# How to get bitcoin price using power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I had this question if you can get bitcoin price history right into excel with power query. The price history is shown in Yahoo finance at the address https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?p=BTC-USD. A lot of people use VBA to get data into excel but I don't like using it. Power query more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is can be done in power query as long as the site has data in a format that is like a table.
FYI you can bring in other formats too like JSON data.

In excel go to Data> Get & Transform Data and use the drop down.
[image]

in the next window paste in the website. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?p=BTC-USD
Some websites have multiple tables. choose the table that you want.
[image]

Next you can transform the data how you want such as filter, drop columns, calculate new columns as you see fit. Once done close and load the data.

You might want to set a data refresh interval that is inside the properties (see image below)
[image]

Do you like the answer, then upvote it, Enjoy.