# How to link two excel sheet in same excel file

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I have two excel sheets

Sheet 1

[image]

sheet 2

[image]

My question is how to joins this two excel sheet for when I delete sheet 1 first record (Dr.John BHRM 11213 Principles of Management) then need to delete first record in second sheet automatically

Anyone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sheet 2 be a powerquery of sheet 1. Look at some examples of [powerquery in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70908744/5091720).
steps.

1. Convert the data in sheet 1 to a table
2. Follow the steps 1 & 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72210898/5091720)
3. Rename & reorder columns.
4. click close and load.
5. You can set refresh conditions under the Data tab.